# Erro ao converter para Json com o Gson

Tags: java, android

Galera, estou tendo este erro ao fazer a conversão do objeto para json. Estou usando o gson. Já tentei enviar o objeto inteiro e tive o mesmo erro, mudei e separei o objeto para tentar localizar onde está o problema, mas sem sucesso.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("cliente",gson.toJson(vend.getCliente()));
    params.put("empresa",gson.toJson(vend.getEmpresa()));
    params.put("endereco",gson.toJson(vend.getEndereco()));
    params.put("carrinho",gson.toJson(vend.getCarrinho()));
    params.put("formPagamento",gson.toJson(vend.getFormPagamento()));
    params.put("troco",gson.toJson(vend.getTrocoParaVenda()));
    params.put("data",gson.toJson(vend.getDataVenda()));
    params.put("valor",gson.toJson(vend.getVlrTotalVenda()));
```

Recebo este erro:

```
                                                                     java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:147)
                                                                       at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
                                                                       at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:551)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:465)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3.write(TypeAdapters.java:169)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3.write(TypeAdapters.java:151)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:112)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:239)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:968)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
                                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
                                                                    at com.google
```

Se possível prefiro enviar o objeto inteiro através do webservice.
Obs: estou usando o volley.

Classe Venda:

```
public class Venda  {
private Long idVenda;
private Date dataVenda;
private String statusVenda;
private Double vlrTotalVenda;
private Pessoa empresa;
private Pessoa cliente;
private Double trocoParaVenda;
private Endereco endereco;
private Boolean retirada;
private List<ItemVenda> carrinho;
private String formPagamento;
```

Classe ItemVenda

```
public class ItemVenda {
private Long idItemVenda;
private Integer quantItemVenda;
private Produto produtoItemVenda;
private Double vlrItemVenda;
@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
private Venda vendaItemVenda;
private List<Ingrediente> ingredientesProduto;
private List<Ingrediente> ingredientesAdicionais;
```

Classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {

private Long idPessoa;
private String nomeFantasiaPessoa;
private String imagem;
private String razaoSocialPessoa;
private String senhaPessoa;
private String telefonePessoa;
private String celularPessoa;
private String emailPessoa;
private String statusPessoa;
private String tipoPessoa;
private String cpfCnpjPessoa;
private String rgIePessoa;
private List<Endereco> enderecos;
private String categoriaPessoa;
private String tempoPreparo;
private Double valorEntrega;
private List<Categoria> categorias;
```

Classe Endereco

```
public class Endereco  {
private Long idEndereco;
private String estadoEndereco;
private String cidadeEndereco;
private String bairroEndereco;
private String ruaEndereco;
private String numeroEndereco;
private String complementoEndereco;
private String cepEndereco;
private Long pessoa;
```

Comment: Qual a definição da classe `ItemVenda`? Se ela tiver uma referência à classe `Venda`, você terá esse problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você provavelmente tem uma dependência circular na sua definição dos dados. Por exemplo, se você tiver essa definição:

```
public class Venda {
    // outros membros
    private List<ItemVenda> carrinho;
}

public class ItemVenda {
    // outros membros
    private Venda venda;
}
```

E o objeto da classe Venda referencia o ItemVenda, que por sua vez referencia a venda original, você terá esse problema.

Se esse for o caso, você pode anotar a propriedade que aponta para a classe "pai" para não ser serializada, de forma a quebrar essa referência circular, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
public class ItemVenda {
    // outros membros
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private Venda venda;
}
```

Se não me engano, você também pode declarar o campo como `transient`, que irá fazer com que ele não seja serializado:

```
public class ItemVenda {
    // outros membros
    private transient Venda venda;
}
```

Comment: opa, tem isso mesmo! acho q deve ser este o problema mesmo, vou testar e retorno com o resultado!

Comment: Eu achei q seria a solução, mas infelizmente não foi desta vez, adicionei as classes restantes se puder ajudar, fico agradecido

Comment: Você tem algum problema semalhante nas classes Pessoa / Categoria? Uma outra coisa pra fazer é comentar cada um dos campos das classes e continuar rodando, até achar aquele que está causando o erro...

Comment: Na Pessoa/Categoria não recebo do servidor convertido em json sem problemas. Já tive com o endereço mas já solucionei colocando apenas o id, a categoria não tem nenhuma dependência de outra classe.

Comment: O problema está no carrinho de compras mesmo.

Comment: Amigo, o problema realmente é onde vc disse, mas como sua solução não funcionou coloquei como Long mesmo, não preciso trazer a classe toda.